# Anyone know of a plugin for WordPress that uses osCommerce?

Tags: plugins

I have be using osCommerce for years, for many sites, for our eCommerce clients and they love it.

We build all our regular sites with WordPress, those clients love that to.

I now want to do my eCommerce sites in WordPress but still wish to use osCommerce.

Is there a plugin for this?

Thanks for your help.
G

Answer (score 1):

either of these any help?  The 1st looks promising

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/oscommerce/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-oscommerce/